# My MongoDB database was lost after running a read-only script

Tags: mongodb

I use MongoDB 4.2 on my local machine (windows 10). I have not changed any configurations, so the default behavior of only accepting local connections should be in place. (I only need to access it locally)

I was running a script that was reading data from my MongoDB, there are no writes to the db in this script. When all the numbers were crunched I noticed weird results, and saw that my database was suddenly gone. I checked my dbpath and the data was gone from there too! Could it be a hack, or was it MongoDB that dropped both the database and the raw data in the dbpath?

I've seen similar questions on this forum, mostly resolved by the author forgetting to reroute to the correct dbpath, which is not the case here. I've checked the log but the log seems to be very limited (I restarted mongod and could only see logging happening after the restart).

Comment: Can you post the script you used?

Comment: @Doryx actually, it more like a several-files project containing a lot of finds. I've run this "script" almost a hundred times and it has never failed. The data in the database is not modified att all (I entered it once, with a completely separate script, which hasn't been ran for a long time), I use this static data for experimenting (think: machine learning dataset which I grab into memory with mongodb's command "find").

Answer (score 0):

MongoDB does not delete all of the files in its data directory.

Most likely either you are checking in the wrong place or something external to MongoDB deleted its files.